# brothy baked beans

Tags: slow-cooking

I've baked beans millions of times!  Today I par boiled my beans and am making them in the crock pot.  The broth always vanishes and thickens up, sometimes I'll need to add extra water.  Not Today!!  For some reason, after 7 hours of cooking, they still have broth like a light chicken soup!  The flavor is amazing and the beans are pretty well cooked, but alas, the broth is, well, too brothy!  I didn't add any ridiculous amounts of water. 
Help!

Comment: It will help if you add the recipe you used, and any differences this time - otherwise, we won't know enough to make suggestions.

Comment: Did you use dfferent beans?

Comment: It sounds like you added too much water at the start

Comment: It's unfortunately unclear whether the par-boiling and the crock pot are part of your usual process or not. Either one being new could result in more water being left after cooking, but if that's what you always do, we might have to look elsewhere for causes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has something to do with being in a crock pot.

In my experience, things that start watery in a crock pot tend to stay that way.  We tried to make scalloped potatoes in a crock pot for Christmas one year, and even after all day the potatoes were cooked, but the liquid hadn't evaporated to form that thick sauce.  I believe this is because of the low heat and lid-- very little water actually evaporates and escapes the pot, leading to very wet dishes (depending on the amount of liquid used at the start) unless they are severely overcooked.

I suspect that making beans in a crock pot requires a bit less water to start with.  As for fixing the pot you have now, I'm not sure.  You could try placing them in a very low oven uncovered, perhaps with only some of the cooking liquid, and bake for a few hours and see if that thickens them up a bit.  You could also add a cornstarch slurry or rue or other thickener to the liquid from your beans and thicken it up that way.  However, I suspect that won't give the result you're looking for.  These beans might just have to be soup.